# is there a way to add an "active" class to a product element

Tags: php, jquery, css, woocommerce, tags

I am trying to filter products by their tag within a woocommerce product tag cloud. My goal is to be able to select multiple tags and have the products with those tags be displayed. I am using PHP and jQuery to do so.

Currently I am using PHP to generate a tag cloud that only displays tags that are related to a certain product category with this code:

```
function custom_product_tag_cloud_func() {
 

    global $wp;
    $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
    if(strpos($current_slug, '/') !== false) {
      // explodable
      $newtest = explode('/', $current_slug);
      $current_slug = array_pop($newtest);
} 

    $args = array(
      'category' => array( $current_slug ),
      'limit' => -1
    );

$products = wc_get_products( $args );
$tags_objects = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
$tags = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );
if (is_array($tags) || is_object($tags)){
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $slug = $tag->slug;
    $tag->id = $slug . " product_tag-" . $slug;
    array_push($tags_objects, $tag);
  }

}
}

$tags_objects = array_unique($tags_objects, SORT_REGULAR);
$tag_cloud = wp_generate_tag_cloud($tags_objects);
$content = '<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><div class="tagcloud">';
$content .= $tag_cloud;
$content .= '</div></div>';
return $content;

}
```

Now each of these products have multiple tags associated with them so I am using jQuery to loop through each product and grab its classes once a tag cloud element is clicked. This element is toggling the class of "active" to indicate that element is selected. Now I want to add an "active" class to those products that have the same tags that the tag cloud element is filtering for. This is the code I have for that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.tag-cloud-link').on("click", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
       $productList = $('.products li').each(function (index,value) 
      { 
         var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
         $.each(classList, function(index, value){
         var result = classList[index].toString().substring(0, 12);
            //console.log(result);
         if(result.substring(value, 12) === 'product_tag-'){
            ourClass = value;
            //console.log(ourClass);

           if($(this).hasClass('ourClass')){
            $(this).addClass('active');
          
         };
         console.log(this);
         }
       });

      });
      });

   

  })
```

&& here are a couple products rendered as HTML

```
<li class="product type-product post-5628 status-publish first instock product_cat-playground-structures product_tag-ages-5-12 product_tag-play-and-park product_tag-playground-sets has-post-thumbnail shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple"></li>

<li class="product type-product post-5620 status-publish instock product_cat-playground-structures product_tag-ages-5-12 product_tag-play-and-park product_tag-playground-sets has-post-thumbnail shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
</li>
```

I am stuck on being able to add that "active" class to the products with the associated tags. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Do I need a separate function that returns a value and then add the class to the returned value?

Comment: and how does a `.tag-cloud-link` look? this line seem wrong `if($(this).hasClass('ourClass'))` should be without quotes?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this more I was able to implement the desired outcome. I had to add the promise() and done() functions to the first object toggle and remove() the active class from the ".product li" elements before looping through each of the ".tag-cloud-link .active" elements, grabbing their classes and then looping through ".products li" again and setting the class of "active".
Here is the code, if it helps anyone else.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('.tag-cloud-link').on("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
       $(this).toggleClass('active',0).promise().done(function(){
           console.log('done toggle');
           $('.products li').removeClass('active');
          $('.tag-cloud-link.active').each(function(){
             var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
             $.each(classList, function(index, value){
             var result = classList[index].toString().substring(0, 12);
             if(result.substring(value, 12) === 'product_tag-'){
                ourClass = value;
                $productList = $('.products li').each(function (index,value) {
                   if($(this).hasClass(ourClass)){
                      $(this).addClass('active');
                   }

                   if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                     $(this).show();
                   }
                   else{
                     $(this).hide();
                   }
                });
             }
             //console.log(this);
          });
       });
      });
    });
   })
```